# How do I .getValues and .setValues from multiple cells in a single column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach, setvalue, getvalue

I have a code that pulls the values from certain cells in Column D from "Enter Blanket Expenses" based on how many properties are checked off in Column F, where the property address appears in Column G if F is checked. I'm splitting expenses evenly between checked properties and the responses appear on "Blanket Responses". If I check four properties and run the script, I get four responses on "Blanket Responses" with the correct amounts, but the first property name is listed four times rather than each property name that's checked. I've taken this as far as my VERY limited knowledge goes, but I'm not sure how to get each individual property to be listed on "Blanket Responses". I feel like it involves using values.foreach but I haven't been able to get that to work properly. Please help! :) Here's the code:

```
function submitDataB() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Enter Blanket Expenses"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Blanket Responses"); //Data Sheet
  var dataRange = ss.getRange("B4:H28")
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var checkbox = row[5];
    var values = [[formSS.getRange("G4:G28").getValues(),
                   formSS.getRange("C4").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D5").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D8").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D9").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D11").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D12").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D13").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D14").getValue(),
                   formSS.getRange("D15").getValue()]];

        if (checkbox == 0)
        {
          continue;
        }

            
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 13).setValues(values);
    }}
```

This is the result with the current code[image]

This is what I want the results to be[image]

Comment: Look into using the new [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String)) function. It allows you to retrieve non-contiguous ranges in one go. Also look at the [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) class; when you call **getRangeList** a **RangeList** instance is returned, so you'll need that reference to lookup the methods you need to manipulate the sub ranges individually.

Comment: Show expected output screenshot and input screenshot

Comment: So sorry, I didn't realize I wasn't receiving notifications. I've edited the post with screenshots for what it results in now and what I need it to result in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

You have to modify this line of code:

```js
//...

var values = [[
    formSS.getRange("G4:G28").getValues(),

//...
```

You are putting every property name in what is going to be a single cell value. This is not a legal operation and as a side effect only the first value of that range is inserted in the corresponding range using this operation:

```js
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 13).setValues(values);
```

With the first value being the content of `G4` cell i.e. "10 Gordon Ridge".

### Proposed modification

You should instead loop through the G column values and insert the corresponding one only when the checkbox is checked.

In order to achieve this you can simply set as a variable the row index when extracting G column values:

```js
//... 

var values = [[
    formSS.getRange(`G${i + 1}`).getValue(),

//...
```

Note: keep in mind that in Javascript arrays the first index is 0 while in Google Spreadsheet A1 Notation is 1. This means that you have to increment the loop index by 1 to obtain the corresponding row index in A1 Notation.

### Reference

[Spreadsheet App Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I needed!