# How to collect data from multiple cells (quantity of 2) and return an output with 2 comma-separated values in one cell? AppScripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, I believe this question is very similar to the following one. However, I want to know if there is an alternative way to write it so that I'm only looping through 2 cells at a time?

[How do I .getValues and .setValues from multiple cells in a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211229/how-do-i-getvalues-and-setvalues-from-multiple-cells-in-a-single-column)

For example, my input is:
Cell E21 = $55
Cell F21 = 1

The desired output is:
$55, 1

The current output is:
$55

This is the code I'm currently using (below). I am not confident about implementing the above linked solution because I definitely don't want to cycle or loop through any complete rows OR columns! If that solution happens to be the only option, please tell me how to write it for my purpose. In the code below, I was hoping it could be written as, "E21:F21" but that's not working! And when I experimented with .getRangeList, I got an error about not converting to Int. So, maybe this is over-communicating, but, I will note that I don't need any decimal point values. The rounded number of $55 flat is great for the first value. Thanks!

```
                 [formSheet.getRange("E21").getValue()],  
                 [formSheet.getRange("F21").getValue()],
```

---

The answer provided below got me mostly there, but I had to have a friend translate it back to me, and ultimately this was the solution! Thanks all!

```
[formSheet.getRange("E21").getValue() + ", " + formSheet.getRange("F21").getValue()]
```

Comment: So do you wish to eliminate F?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper I hope this explanation helps to clarify: I am using  one Tab on a Google Sheet as the Input and another Tab on the same Google Sheet as the Output. The input is a form, so people will add their data into both E21 and F21. However, I would like to read both items combined in one cell as my output. Here is a description/story of the usage:  "We are hiring a Level 4 Tech at the rate of $55/hour and there will be 2 Techs" therefore $55, 2 (or $55, 1 for 1 tech as per the original example above).

Comment: @Cooper Does the above clarification not meet the Minimal Reproducible Example requirement? I'm afraid I'm not advanced enough to phrase it appropriately. I'm a super-beginner at this.

Comment: Not really but I think my example will provide you with what you require.  Although some modification is required.

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Are you looking for `.getValues()`? Note the `s` at the end of `.getValue()`

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper I got syntax errors left and right when trying to integrate this so I cannot mark it as solved for myself, although I'm sure it is solved.

Comment: I tested my example so you are going to have to be more specific with the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer I ultimately used:

```
[formSheet.getRange("E21").getValue() + ", " + 
formSheet.getRange("F21").getValue()]
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code:

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange("A2:B" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().map(r => [`${r[0]},${r[1]}`])
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  sh.getRange(2,4,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs)
}
```

My input and output:

| COL1 | COL2 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 12 |  | 4,12 |
| 5 | 19 |  | 5,19 |
| 16 | 4 |  | 16,4 |
| 4 | 18 |  | 4,18 |
| 11 | 12 |  | 11,12 |
| 13 | 15 |  | 13,15 |
| 19 | 7 |  | 19,7 |
| 14 | 10 |  | 14,10 |
| 10 | 6 |  | 10,6 |
| 9 | 18 |  | 9,18 |
| 18 | 9 |  | 18,9 |
| 19 | 10 |  | 19,10 |
| 19 | 4 |  | 19,4 |
| 8 | 9 |  | 8,9 |
| 4 | 4 |  | 4,4 |
| 14 | 19 |  | 14,19 |
| 3 | 16 |  | 3,16 |
| 5 | 18 |  | 5,18 |
| 16 | 19 |  | 16,19 |
| 13 | 5 |  | 13,5 |