# How to *reverse* comma separated output that combines data from 2 specific cells?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, input

I wrote code (based on [How to collect data from multiple cells (quantity of 2) and return an output with 2 comma-separated values in one cell? AppScripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219919/how-to-collect-data-from-multiple-cells-quantity-of-2-and-return-an-output-wit/72468738#72468738)) that returns an output of comma separated values. It works great.

For example,

Input:

A1 = 1

B1 = 2

Results in Output:
1, 2

Here is that code:

```
[formSheet.getRange("E25").setValue(row[2]) + ", " + 
formSheet.getRange("F25").setValue(row[2])],
```

The context is a spreadsheet-based Form. (No, the generic Google Forms does not work for our purposes).

Now I got myself in a pickle because users are requesting the Feature of being able to Retrieve and Edit their Form.

Ok. I can do that.

Until....

I get to those Output cells that are comma separated. Whoops. Is there a way to reverse this process, so that each value goes back into its respective Input cell?

Output (source):
1, 2

Retrieved Results:

A1 = 1

B1 = 2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and setValues:

```
formSheet.getRange('E25:F25').setValues([
  outputSheet.getRange('A25').getValue().split(', ')
])
```